# volatility forecast with "for" loop for GARCH family model

Tags: r

I am using a beta-t-egarch package and unfortunately it does not have rolling forecast, so I would like to manually make it in R. The basic idea for the loop is that it runs the code then makes forecast, keep the forecasted value in forecast data.frame and goes back, re-estimates the model, forecast and add that value to forecast data. frame and etc until loops finishes. My problem in the loop is that it only forecasts for one day and does not re-estimate the model and forecast again.

I looked on the web and I could only construct this code:

```
start = 1
finish = 65    
for (k in start:finish) {    
WIGcomp1<- tegarch(WIG$r)
forecast <- predict(WIGcomp1, n.ahead = 1)
forecast[k-start+1]
}
```

My data start from:

```
> head(WIG)
           Date      WIG             r
5233 2014-01-02 51865.89  0.0112776612
5234 2014-01-03 51497.81 -0.0071220662
5235 2014-01-07 50444.78 -0.0206600098
5236 2014-01-08 50482.93  0.0007559867
5237 2014-01-09 49753.03 -0.0145638931
5238 2014-01-10 49796.50  0.0008733342
> tail(WIG)
           Date      WIG            r
5293 2014-03-28 51831.67  0.003646887
5294 2014-03-31 52373.47  0.010398813
5295 2014-04-01 52571.51  0.003774173
5296 2014-04-02 52761.31  0.003603819
5297 2014-04-03 52376.18 -0.007326249
5298 2014-04-04 52660.68  0.005417159
```

Structure of the data is:

```
'data.frame':   66 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Date: Date, format: "2014-01-02" "2014-01-03" "2014-01-07" "2014-01-08" ...
 $ WIG : num  51866 51498 50445 50483 49753 ...
 $ r   : num  0.011278 -0.007122 -0.02066 0.000756 -0.014564 ...
```

If anything needs to be amended or added please let me know and I will gladly do it.Thank you in advance.

Comment: rugarch is a pretty nice package for vol forecasting, it's got a lot of different things, including rolling forecasts

Comment: Hi DMT, I also use rugarch for GRJ model, and I agree it has amazing functions in there, however, the R package I use is quite new (betategarch) and does not have a rolling forecast which why I run into problem when performing forecasting. I do appreciate the answer and the help.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your code is that you are calculating the same forecast over and over, because rather than using `k` to isolate a moving window, you are just using the entire set of data each time. In this scenario, there is only one possibly forecast to make, and it uses your entire data vector (`WIGcomp1<- tegarch(WIG$r)`). For example, consider this data set, and a slightly modified version of your code:

```
library(betategarch)
##
set.seed(1234)
Data <- data.frame(
  Date=seq.Date(
    from=as.Date("2014-01-02"),
    by="day",
    length.out=66),
  WIG=rnorm(66,mean=51000,sd=1500),
  r=rnorm(66,mean=0,sd=.005))
##
##
your.fun <- function(){
  start = 1
  finish = 65
  Forecast <- NULL
  for (k in start:finish) {    
    WIGcomp1<- tegarch(Data$r)
    Forecast[k] <- predict(WIGcomp1, n.ahead = 1)
    ##forecast[k-start+1]
  }
  Forecast
}
##
> your.fun()
 [1] 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116
[10] 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116
[19] 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116
[28] 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116
[37] 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116
[46] 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116
[55] 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116 0.003424116
[64] 0.003424116 0.003424116
```

Since you aren't using a moving window of source data, it just makes the same prediction over and over. An alternative solution would be to use a moving subset of data to make successive 1 step ahead predictions from a moving window that spans `n` days (`n = 10` in my example below). This is representative of a situation in which each day you get a new observed value, and use that data point and the previous 9 days of data to predict tomorrow's value.

```
rolling.forecast <- function(Df=Data,Var="r",Window=10,nAhead=1){
  ##
  fCast <- rollapplyr(
    Df[,Var], width=Window, function(x){
      predict(
        tegarch(x),
        n.ahead=nAhead)
    })
  ##
  newData <- cbind(
    Df,
    Forecast=c(
      rep(NA,Window-1),
      fCast))
  ##
  return(newData)
}
##
> NewData <- rolling.forecast()
> head(NewData,10)
         Date      WIG             r    Forecast
1  2014-01-02 49189.40 -5.693039e-03          NA
2  2014-01-03 51416.14  6.839136e-03          NA
3  2014-01-04 52626.66  6.647824e-03          NA
4  2014-01-05 47481.45  1.682364e-03          NA
5  2014-01-06 51643.69  3.446419e-05          NA
6  2014-01-07 51759.08 -2.277344e-03          NA
7  2014-01-08 50137.89 -1.832620e-03          NA
8  2014-01-09 50180.05  3.241433e-03          NA
9  2014-01-10 50153.32  1.035135e-02          NA
10 2014-01-11 49664.94 -7.669921e-04 0.003737219
> tail(NewData)
         Date      WIG            r    Forecast
61 2014-03-03 51984.88 -0.003157046 0.255080969
62 2014-03-04 54823.49 -0.007566441 0.011048830
63 2014-03-05 50947.86 -0.003180499 0.012665863
64 2014-03-06 49995.55  0.001131508 0.002204160
65 2014-03-07 50988.59  0.005068452 0.047949976
66 2014-03-08 53665.63  0.001263751 0.001458638
```

When you do this, you will of course only be able to generate `N - Window + 1` new values; where `N` is the number of observations in your data, and `Window` is the span of the rolling window of data. Since I used the function `rollapplyr` which has a default `align` value of `right` (adapted from the more general function `rollapply` in the package `zoo`), the first `Window-1 = 9` observations are set to `NA`.

Comment: Nrussell, I do not know how to thank you. Thank you very much for taking the the time and explaining and making the codes, I really appreciate it. I am doing this project but I have been stuck for some time in making forecast with moving window and n.roll functions. Rugarch package has all of them, however the R package I use for this model is pretty new and does not have those functions yet. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @Tim I'm currently having similar problems. However, I'm using rugarch package. I have posted the question statsexchange here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/524755/rugarch-voatlilty-forecasting-in-r-1-time-step-ahead-and-continuous-evaluating. Can you guys help? My goal is the exact same as done here.